# "*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated" when trying to embedd python in a C program

Tags: python, c, dynamic-linking, python-embedding, ldd

I want to compile the following C program, and then use it on another machine that doesn't have Python installed.

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("print('Hello World!')\n");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

My current approach is to use `ldd` to copy the required shared libraries to a directory, and then add the directory to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on the target Machine.

---

Machine 1 (with Python installed)

```
$ gcc test.c $(python-config --cflags) $(python-config --ldflags)

$ cp $(ldd a.out) lib

$ ls lib/
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  libc.so.6  libcrypt.so.1  libdl.so.2  libm.so.6  libpthread.so.0  libpython3.7m.so.1.0  libutil.so.1

$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./lib/ ./a.out
Hello World!
```

---

Machine 2 (without python)

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./lib/ ./a.out
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
Aborted
```

What is going wrong here?

---

I have simulated the Machines using docker. Machine 1 is the `python` image, while Machine 2 is the `ubuntu` image.

Machine 1:

```
$ uname -a
Linux 370618d9d26e 4.9.125-linuxkit #1 SMP Fri Sep 7 08:20:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ python --version
Python 3.7.4
```

```
libc6-amd64, Version: 2.28-10
```

Machine 2:

```
$ uname -a
Linux 4962469663b8 4.9.125-linuxkit #1 SMP Fri Sep 7 08:20:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
libc6-amd64, Version: 2.27-3ubuntu1
```

Comment: What *exact* Python version are you using? What *exact* Linux distributions are involved? What is the *exact* version of `libc.so` on *each* machine? What are the kernel version of both Linux systems?

Comment: Did you consider to replace your embedded Python by some embedded [Lua](http://lua.org/) interpreter? If that is ok in your case, you might avoid weeks of work!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Updated answer. Note: The lib dir contains `libc.so.6 `

Comment: Looks like this is a problem that originates from libc version mismatch. I tried to remove libc from the lib folder, and use the available libc, but that ofcourse raises `/root/a.out: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /root/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0)` :(

Comment: My overall recommendation remains. To *embed* an interpreter in your program, prefer [Lua](http://lua.org/) or [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) to Python (both are *designed* to be embedded, not just embeddable by accident, like Python). Because [Python can be embedded](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/) but usually *should not be*. Python is good enough as a plain interpreter, and just passable as an embeddable one.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile `-static` as well, and libraries will be bundled with your executable.
That might be in your `--cflags`, but also consider using `-o MyCoolAppName` so you get something instead of `a.out`

```
man gcc
```

for good [sleeplytime reading](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc).

```
> NAME
>        gcc - GNU project C and C++ compiler
> 
> SYNOPSIS
>        gcc [-c|-S|-E] [-std=standard]
>            [-g] [-pg] [-Olevel]
>            [-Wwarn...] [-Wpedantic]
>            [-Idir...] [-Ldir...]
>            [-Dmacro[=defn]...] [-Umacro]
>            [-foption...] [-mmachine-option...]
>            [-o outfile] [@file] infile...
```

Comment: static linking fails with `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.7m`

Comment: Here is the full command 

`gcc test.c --static -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -L/usr/local/lib -lpython3.7m -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm`

Comment: Either way, compiling for MacOS won't allow static linking at all, so ...